# Object going out of scope, but delegate is set, using ARC

Tags: objective-c, scope, automatic-ref-counting

I'm so very sorry for the unclear title, but I can't explain it shortly.

I am basically wondering what happens if you use ARC and you have a method like this:

```
- (void)fooMethod:(NSURLRequest *)fooReq
{
    NSURLConnection *fooConn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:fooReq delegate:self];
    [fooConn start];
}
```

So fooConn goes out of scope at the end of the fooMethod, but will I still receive callbacks? In other words: because there aren't any more references, will it get dealloc'd (or something like that) immediately, or will it stay in memory and handle the request because the delegate is still set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately
```

The connection retains delegate. It releases delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails

Comment: So the delegate doesn't have to have a reference to the connection, neat-o!

Comment: Interestingly, this is one of the few places where a delegate is retained.

Comment: Well, I could see why it would be retained here, specifically. That's also why I asked :) Because as far as I understand, the connection basically communicates everything through callbacks. But interesting bit of information!

Answer (score 3):

That totally depends on what `NSURLConnection` does behind the scenes. If the retain count drops to zero, then `fooConn` will be `dealloc`'ed still and one would assume no more callbacks would be made then.

Now, I think that `NSURLConnection` behind the scenes does get retained somewhere in the hierarchy of things so you would in fact receive callbacks. However with `NSURLConnection` I usually keep a strong reference to it lying around to be on the safe side. After all, you as the caller of it want to own it and you want to ensure that you will keep getting the delegate callbacks and not be at the mercy of whatever happens to it under the hood.

So, in short, if I were you I'd keep a strong reference to it to ensure you won't have to worry.

Comment: I will :) I was just curious as to what would 'theoretically' happen :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem :-). Curiosity here is not a bad thing at all. My advice would be if you have this curiosity then just err on the side of caution. Nobody except the guys developing the internals will know what happens behind the scenes. Not to mention the fact it might retain it now and then later down the line they might change it to not retain.

Comment: A colleague also just pointed out that even if the object stays 'active', my object has no reference to it, even though it is the delegate, so there is actually no way to set the delegate to nil, for example.

Comment: Yes that's true, unless you wanted to set the delegate to `nil` during a delegate callback. Then you'd have a reference to it as it's passed in. But yes - keep a reference is the right thing to do anyway :-).

Answer (score 1):

`fooConn` is a local variable without any ownership qualifier so ARC will infer it as strong. Therefore ARC will retain the value returned by `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` when storing it into `foxConn`; and when exiting `fooMethod:` ARC will clean up by releasing `fooConn`.

That the delegate references the current instance will have no effect on this.

If you wish the `NSURLConnection` to exist after `fooMethod:` returns one way is to store it into an instance variable (which ARC also infers as strong, so no ownership qualifier required there either). If you do this when the class instance itself is no longer reference ARC will release the `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: I was just curious, usually I keep a reference just to be sure :) Thanks!